# Matching everything except for a character followed by a newline

Tags: python, regex

This seems like a simple match, but I'm unable to figure out how to match all text that starts with a known block of text and ends with a semicolon + newline. What I have right now mostly works:

```
pattern = r'''[ ]+(value \w+\n)([^;]+)'''
```

For an example section of text that allows me to parse:

```
   value Y1N5NALC
      1 = 'Yes'  
      5 = 'No'  
      7 = 'Not ascertained' ;
   value AGESCRN
      15 = '15 years'  
      16 = '16 years';
```

However, if any of the key/value pairs contain a semicolon *in the string* the match fails early since the regex is looking for any semicolon. An example:

```
   value Y1N5NALC
      1 = 'Yes'  
      5 = 'No;Maybe'  
      7 = 'Not ascertained' ;
```

What I'd like to do is end the match by looking for a `semicolon` + `Optional(space or tab)` + `newline`. Using `([^;\n]+)` fails since the newline gets match to the negative.

Comment: What is the actual regex call? You want some flags with that.

Comment: Are there spaces before "value" or are the spaces in your example just an artifact of the code block?

Comment: @tdelaney there are spaces (and sometimes tabs?) that could precede the word `value`.

Comment: A better approach to this would be to describe your match in terms of lines; something like `^[ \t]*value \w+$(?:\s+\d+ = .*$)*` matches a `value` line followed by all succeeding assignment lines. This way you don't even need to test for the semicolon, unless your aim is validation. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/znCVLE/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?sm)^ +(value \w+\n)(.*?);$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZqqHgj/3).

*Details*:

- `(?sm)` - `re.S` and `re.M` are on
- `^` - start of a line
- `+` - one or more spaces
- `(value \w+\r?\n)` - Group 1: `value`, space, one or more word chars, and and an LF line break
- `(.*?)` -  Group 2:
- `;` - a `;`
- `$` - at the end of a line.

In case there can be CRLF endings, you need

```py
(?sm)^ +(value \w+\r?\n)(.*?);\r?$
```

Comment: Consdiering OP's note that spaces or tabs could precede "value", it may be best to use `(?sm)^\s*(value \w+\n)(.*?);$`

Comment: It is fine as is, if there is need to match horizontal whitespace, `' +'` can be replaced with `'[^\S\r\n]+'`